# Draw xy axis rotation by angle

Tags: axis, angle

I would like to draw axis rotation such as this. I can't find anything similar in other questions.. Can someone help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy with `TiKz`.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (7,0);
\draw [->,line width=2pt] (O) -- (A)node [right]{$x$};
\draw [->,line width=2pt] (O) -- (90:7)node [right]{$y$};
\draw [->,line width=2pt,dashed] (O) -- (30:7)coordinate(C) node [right]{$x^\prime$};
\draw [->,line width=2pt,dashed] (O) -- (120:7)node [right,xshift=2mm]{$y^\prime$};
\pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.1,angle radius=2cm] {angle = A--O--C};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]